# What does it mean by acta?

Tags: math-history

There are a lot math journals with title "acta" includes, for instance, Acta Mathematica, acta arithmetica, etc. Would you explain what "acta" means?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Acta is the plural of actum, a Latin word refering to $($official$)$ papers or documents.

Answer (score 5):

In latin, $actum$ means $fact$ and $acta$ is, in latin, the plural form of $actum$.

Comment: The same dual meaning exists in English as well, see [deed](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/deed#Noun).

Comment: @Lucian. One expression which is nice is $aliquid$ $acti$ which stands for $achieved$ $progress$. When shall we see a journal with that in its name ? People could think that it is about the thermodynamics of the liquid phase !! Cheers :)

Comment: You are very welcome !